# How to turn on jQuery support on Aptana Studio 3 on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: jquery, ubuntu, aptana3

I'd like to use jQuery support.

I've downloaded and installed Aptana Studio 3.0 on Ubuntu workstation. I've created new web project, downloaded development version of jquery library from jquery.com, wrote simple script and run it. It works. But autocomplition doesn't work: Aptana for Ctrl-Space doesn't show any jQuery methods.

There are lots of solutions like this: [Aptana 3 jquery code assist/hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891269/aptana-3-jquery-code-assist-hinting) .
I can not try it because I can not find Commands or Install Bundle menus in Aptana on Linux.

What's wrong? What I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I taken sources of javascript-jquery.ruble from https://github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble and copied it to Aptana_Studio_3/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/91/1/.cp/bundle

It's very strange method, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

For reappear menu "Commands"

1. Click with right-click on Toolbar
2. Click on "Customize Perspective..."
3. Click on "Menu Visibility"
4. Uncheck "Commands"
5. Click "OK"
6. Click with right-click on Toolbar
7. Click on "Customize Perspective..."
8. Click on "Menu Visibility"
9. Check "Commands"
10. Click "OK"

Work for me in Ubuntu 12.04 with Aptana Studio 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Commands menu if you right-click on an open file; from here on just follow the instructions on the website.