# aptana with Code completion and syntax highlighting for third party library

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, aptana

I am currently coding with eclipse + aptana plugin for a web project. I need to use a third party library called d3. My problem now is how to get aptana working with this library in terms of Code completion and syntax highlighting. 
I saw few similar questions before like [Add javascript code assist for d3.js in Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140885/add-javascript-code-assist-for-d3-js-in-aptana-studio-3), or [Aptana 3 jquery code assist/hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891269/aptana-3-jquery-code-assist-hinting)...but they didnot end well.  Any one has a thought???

Meanwhile, I also would like to know how to open **Code Assist Profiles** from aptana in eclipse. Is there a view or window for this option?

Comment: come on. No one??????????????

Comment: I am searching this problem too but getting no positive result by now.